# How to create a Windows 7 Recovery disk if it's home edition and it's broken at the moment?

Tags: windows-7, recovery-disk

Windows 7 can't load to the Welcome screen. It just boots to a black screen with a blinking cursor. How to create a Windows 7 Recovery DVD disk if I have a second laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate installed? I have a Windows 7 Recovery disk for Windows Ultimate, but it' not compatible with my Windows Home.

Comment: Are you able to get in to Windows if you start in safe mode? Press F8 before the 'loading' screen comes up when you turn on your PC and try that. You can then look at system restore or look through the event log to work out what's happening.

Coincidentally my PC does this with certain USB devices attached (i.e. printer, joystick - things that need a bit of power). So you could also try unplugging all but keyboard and mouse and see if that helps. YMMV!

Comment: Thanks! Got there by F8. It displayed that there was smth wrong with attaching usb devices to it. I connected phone to laptop via usb and the loptop battery died and I was unable to load Windows. What it might be? Why so strange behavior?

Comment: How to write recovery dvd or cd for current version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this youtube tutorial entitled **Windows 7: System Repair USB** you will need:

a USB Flash Drive at least 256Mb

a blank CD, or Daemon Tools Lite

The tutorial will take you through the steps , be sure to click on Show More underneath the Video for the Win 7 repair disk link

The video link is:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPKu4cf1_Os

Comment: How to manually create system restore point?

Comment: i'm not entirely sure about that